# Unable to add include ANE File in ANT Script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ant, air

I wanted to create an ANT Script to create build in one click for my Flex Mobile Project.

My app using some native extension file (`.ane` file). When I tried to run the ANT script it saying -

> An implementation for native extension 'com.example.mobile.extensions.NativeFeature' required by the application was not found for the target platform

I'm using the following code to include ane file in ANT Script.

```
<compiler.external-library-path dir="${basedir}/ane" append="true">   
    <include name="**/*.ane"/>   
</compiler.external-library-path>
```

Also added the same extensionId in `myApp-app.xml` file which I used in my `extension.xml` file.

Comment: Several questions:  What platforms have you implemented in your .ane?  What platform are you targeting in your Ant script?  How far into your script do you get before you see the error (i.e. during the mxmlc or the ADT call?)  Finally, could you post your build script (or at least the snippets where you invoke mxmlc and adt)?

Comment: @Brain I am using Flash Builder 4.7 and AIR sdk 17. Wanted to automate build process so creating ANT script. My app is using some ANE file and I am including these ane files in mxmlc but after running the ANT Script I am getting this error in ADT execute.

Comment: Thank you @Brian your questions help me to find the root cause of the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. Basically I need to add `-extdr` argument in ADT command. By adding `-extdir ${basedir}/ane` in ADT command I am able to resolve the problem. Added sample code below.

```
<target name="package.android" >
  <echo message="Packaging for Android"/>
    <exec executable="${ADT}" dir="${build.dir}/android">
            <arg line="-package
                        -target apk
                        -storetype ${build.storetype}
                        -keystore ${android.cert}
                        -storepass ${android.cert.password}
                        ${app.name}
                        ${app.name}-app.xml
                        ${app.name}.swf
                        -extdir ${basedir}/ane
                        "/>
        </exec>
</target>
```